# Query database and store results in array in drupal module

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I have a table in my database called `gsm_tariff`. Basically I just want to run a simple select query

```
"SELECT * FROM {gsm_tariff} WHERE Country='Afghanistan'"
```

and store the results in an array. Can anyone help me with how to do this please? I know where to put the code and everything; I just need the code to do the query and store the results in an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array();

$result = db_query('SELECT * FROM {gsm_tariff} WHERE Country = "%s"', 'Afghanistan');

while ($record = db_fetch_object($result)) {
   $array[] = $record->(data to reference);   
}
```

Note that I don't know the field you want to reference given the question, but it would be in the $record object.